# Iteración entre renglones de un Dataframe - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un problema con un código que estoy trabajando, el contexto es que quiero iterar a través de todos los renglones de un dataframe para aplicar una función tomando el valor de una columna en todos los renglones, EL PROBLEMA es que al ejecutar el código me di cuenta de que únicamente le está aplicando la función al último renglón del dataframe, es decir, no lee y aplica al primero, solo al último valor. ¿Me podrían ayudar? Adjunto código y el dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('hola.txt', sep='|', header=None, warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False, skipinitialspace=(True))

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    def longitud_fecha(lon_fecha,fecha_beneficio):
        if lon_fecha != fecha_beneficio:
            return('La longitud del campo no es válida, el número de caracteres del campo es: %r ' %lon_fecha)
        else:
            return('La longitud del campo es correcta')

    lon_fecha=len(df.iloc[i,17].item())
    fecha_beneficio=8
    diagnostico=longitud_fecha(lon_fecha,fecha_beneficio)

print(df.iloc[i,17], diagnostico)
```

El Dataframe es (los valores en negrita son los que debe leer):

AALM460718MOCLPR05|ALTAMIRANO|LOPEZ|MARINA|19460718|OC|M|NO|NO|09|08|08215|S293|13|20|153|9999|**20220817**|01|251
CUGG691212MCHRND05|CRUZ|GONZALEZ|GUADALUPE|19691212|CH|M|NO|NO|09|08|08215|S293|10|08|027|9999|**20220325**|01|251

output:

20220325(La longitud del campo es correcta)

Como pueden ver, no me regresa el diagnostico para el primer renglón del dataframe, únicamente me regresa el del Segundo, incluso si borro el valor del primer renglón me retorna dos diagnósticos, pero para el mismo renglón (el último). Espero me puedan ayudar

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Tenes un error de concepto en cuanto como funciona Python. En Python, las variables se pueden sobreescribir. O sea en el caso del primer renglón, hace un diagnostico y lo guarda en diagnostico. Luego, en el segundo hace otro diagnostico y sobreescribe el valor anterior de diagnostico con el nuevo.

Comment: Lo mismo pasa en el bucle for. Como el print está fuera del bucle for, la i tiene el ultimo valor que el bucle for seteó.

Comment: Oh ya veo, entonces tendría que hacer que no se sobreescriba el diagnostico no?

Comment: Basicamente meter el print dentro del bucle for no?

Comment: Digamos que eso te iría mostrando los valores que toma diagnostico. En terminos de debug, es util. Pero la variable diagnostico se seguirá sobreescribiendo. Tu objetivo es solo ver los valores que toma diagnostico, o utilizar todos los diagnosticos más adelante?

Comment: El objetivo es que me muestre los valores que toma diagnostico iterando en todos los renglones del dataframe

Comment: En ese caso, si no necesitas que los diagnosticos anteriores se conserven y solo irlos mostrando en pantalla. Si, esa sería la solución. Peeero, recuerda que la variable diagnostico se sigue sobreescribiendo y poner el print dentro del for no cambiará eso.

Comment: Oh ya veo, ¿Cómo puedo evitar que no se sobreescriba?

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a evitar que se sobreescriba, sin el no. Python tiene objetos especiales llamados [listas](https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-list-python/), que nos permiten tener multiples valores en una sola variable. La incializas una vez fuera del for con `diagnostico = []` y le vas agregando cada diagnostico al final con su método append (`diagnostico.append(valor)`)

Comment: La respuesta de HeytalePazguato es el camino correcto. Eso te devolverá una Serie de Pandas. Sin embargo, espero que hayas aprendido algo nuevo de mis comentarios c:

Comment: Muchas gracias, te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Con el siguiente `dataframe` de ejemplo (Agregué una fila con un 7 dígitos en la columna 17 para mostrar el funcionamiento):

```
                   0           1         2          3         4   5  6   7   \
0  AALM460718MOCLPR05  ALTAMIRANO     LOPEZ     MARINA  19460718  OC  M  NO   
1  CUGG691212MCHRND05        CRUZ  GONZALEZ  GUADALUPE  19691212  CH  M  NO   
2  CUGG691212MCHRND05        CRUZ  GONZALEZ  GUADALUPE  19691212  CH  M  NO   

   8   9   10    11    12  13  14   15    16        17  18   19  
0  NO   9   8  8215  S293  13  20  153  9999  20220817   1  251  
1  NO   9   8  8215  S293  10   8   27  9999  20220325   1  251  
2  NO   9   8  8215  S293  10   8   27  9999   2022325   1  251
```

Puedes hacerlo facilmente utilizando [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', sep='|', header=None, on_bad_lines='warn', skipinitialspace=(True))
print(df[17].apply(lambda x: 'La longitud del campo es correcta' if len(str(x)) == 8 else f'La longitud del campo no es válida, el número de caracteres del campo es: {len(str(x))}'))
```

Esto imprime la siguiente serie:

```
0                                            La longitud del campo es correcta
1                                            La longitud del campo es correcta
2  La longitud del campo no es válida, el número de caracteres del campo es: 7
Name: 17, dtype: object
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo estoy aplicando para ver el resultado, muchas muchas gracias

Comment: amigo, me dice que la sintaxis es incorrecta :O

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece exactamente? ¿Qué versión de `pandas` utilizas? Porque en la pregunta utilizas argumentos que han sido marcados como próximas modificaciones, están marcados como deprecados.

Comment: Me aparece 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' utilizo pandas 1.5.0, y el IDE spyder

Comment: Lo ejecute en la terminal y dice que el error está en ... {len(str(x))}'))

Comment: ¿Pusiste la `f` antes del `string`? ¿Qué versión de `python` estás utilizando?

Comment: Sí, si la puse, la versión 3.9

Comment: Por favor entra a este [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249520/iteracion-entre-renglones-de-un-dataframe-python-pandas) y pon el código tal cual lo estás ejecutando para revisarlo.

Comment: @DonovanMendoza, como nunca entraste al chat y no hay retroalimentación asumo que era un error de dedo al transcribir el código. Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Estimado @HeytalePazguato, te pido una disculpa se me junto mucho el trabajo y ya no pude entrar, asumes bien, la solución estaba en cómo había transcrito el código, te agradezco mucho tu ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Buen día @DonovanMendoza, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)